# Why rpy2.robjects.lib.grid.viewport() return ListVector，but not viewport?

Tags: python, ggplot2, rpy2

I am trying to plot several subgraphs in one graph using `rpy2.robjects.lib.grid.viewport()`, and this is the code:

```
from rpy2.robjects.lib import grid
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 as ggplot2
from rpy2 import robjects
dataf=robjects.DataFrame({'year':IntVector([2000,2001,2002,2001,2002]),
      'pop':IntVector([1.5,1.7,3.6,2.4,2.9]),'GDP':IntVector([4,5.3,6,7,8])})
grid.newpage()
lt=grid.layout(1,2)
vp=grid.viewport(layout=lt)
print(type(vp))
vp.push()
gp=ggplot2.ggplot(dataf)
vp = grid.viewport(**{'layout.pos.col':1, 'layout.pos.row': 1})
pp=gp+ggplot2.aes_string(x='pop',y='GDP')+ggplot2.geom_point()
pp.plot(vp=vp)
vp = grid.viewport(**{'layout.pos.col':2, 'layout.pos.row': 1})
pp=gp+ggplot2.aes_string(x='pop',y='GDP',col='factor(year)')+ggplot2.geom_point()
pp.plot(vp=vp）
```

But there in an error when executing "vp.push()". The error is as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "F:\pythonspace\pythontoR2.py", line 15, in 
>       vp.push()
>   AttributeError: 'ListVector' object has no attribute 'push'

I am using python3.4 and R3.2.1,rpy2 2.7.6 .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an oversight in `rpy2.robjects.lib.grid`.

Try replacing

```
vp=grid.viewport(layout=lt)
```

with

```
vp=grid.Viewport(grid.viewport(layout=lt))
```

(and may be file a bug report on the bug tracker for rpy2)

**note: This filed as [issue #350](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/350/), and a fix in the repos (will be included with rpy2 release 2.8.0)**